# Variance and Covariance computation

Tags: random-walk, variance, covariance

We have a random walk defined as:
$$m_t=m_{t-1}+u_t$$
with $u_t$ representing a noise i.i.d. with expectation 0 and variance $\sigma^2_u$. Then, we define:
$$p_t=m_t+q_tc$$
where $q_t=+1$ or $-1$ and $c$ is a constant. Notice also that $q_t$ are assumed to be serially independent and independent form both $m_t$ and $p_t$.
Could someone help me to understand, step by step, how to get that:
$$\operatorname{Var}(p_t-p_{t-1})=2c^2+\sigma^2_u$$
$$\operatorname{Cov}((p_{t-1}-p_{t-2}),(p_t-p_{t-1}))=-c^2 \text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{Var}(p_t-p_{t-1}) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{Var} \big((m_t+q_tc) - (m_{t-1}+q_{t-1}c)\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{Var} (m_t-m_{t-1}) + c^2\operatorname{Var}( q_t-q_{t-1})
\end{align}
The last line is valid if $c$ is a constant (i.e. not random) and $q_t-q_{t-1}$ is not correlated with $m_t-m_{t-1}.$ And the first term in the last line above is $\operatorname{Var}(u_t).$

As above, we have
\begin{align}
p_t -  p_{t-1} = {} & (m_t-m_{t-1}) + c(q_t-q_{t-1}) \\
p_{t-1} - p_{t-2} = {} & (m_{t-1} - m_{t-1}) + c(q_{t-1}-q_{t-2})
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{Cov}((p_{t-1}-p_{t-2}),(p_t-p_{t-1})) \\[8pt]
\text{and } & \operatorname{Cov}(m_t-m_{t-1}, m_{t-1}- m_{t-2}) \\
= {} & \operatorname{Cov}(u_t,u_{t-1}) \\
= {} & 0 \text{ ?} \\[8pt]
\text{and } & \operatorname{Cov}(q_t-q_{t-1},q_{t-1}-q_{t-2}) \\
= {} & \operatorname{Cov}(-q_{t-1}, q_{t-1}) \\
& \text{if the other covariances here are 0.}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot different fundamental facts in my question, which, thanks to your observations, I've just added by editing. Your answer is extremely clear and useful, thanks a lot. I've understood how to get to variance result. Just one thing..as to covariance computation, how can we get to the final result $-c^2$? Since I cannot understand the passage $Cov(q_t-q_{t-1},q_{t-1}-q_{t-2})=Cov(-q_{t-1},q_{t-1})$

Comment: @user600927 : $$ \begin{align} & \operatorname{Cov}(q_t-q_{t-1}, q_{t-1}-q_{t-2}) \\ {} \\ = {} & \operatorname{Cov}(q_t, q_{t-1}-q_{t-2}) - \operatorname{Cov}(q_{t-1}, q_{t-1}-q_{t-2}) \\ {} \\ = {} & 0 - \operatorname{Cov} (q_{t-1}, q_{t-1}-q_{t-2}) \\ {} \\ = {} & -\operatorname{Cov}(q_{t-1},q_{t-1}) + \operatorname{Cov}( q_{t-1},q_{t-2}) \\ {} \\ = {} & -\operatorname{Cov}(q_{t-1},q_{t-1}) + 0 \\ {} \end{align} $$

Comment: Thank You a lot!!!!!!